# FFMPEG not resizing a video properly

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFMPEG to resize a video using -s 480x272. Unfortunately something is causing FFMPEG to output a video with 483x272.

For those curious this is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i 'BirdyNamNam.mp4' -an -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -vpre fastfirstpass -b 512k -bt 512k -threads 2 -s 480x272 BirdyNamNam1256333420.mp4

ffmpeg -i 'BirdyNamNam.mp4' -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -pass 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -b 512k -bt 512k -threads 2 -y -s 480x272 BirdyNamNam1256333420.mp4
```

Is FFMPEG trying to maintain the aspect ratio or something like that? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force FFmpeg to respect your size by adding this to your command:

```
-aspect:v 480:272
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You probably want `-padbottom`, `-padtop`, `-padleft`, `-padright` or--if you don't mind losing some of the frame--`-cropbottom`, `-croptop`, `-cropleft` and `-cropright`.

Comment: These options have been removed from recent FFmpeg, so this answer is no longer valid. The `-vf "pad=width:height:x:y"` (or `crop`) filter should be used instead. See: [How can I crop a video with ffmpeg?](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg/4571#4571)